# Compute the Database Schema Size

Tags: plsql

I want to find the size of `Table`, `Data_Space_Used`, `Index_Space_Used`, `Unused_Space` etc but `exec sp_spaceused` doesn't work.

I need to define first the table with columns as referred above?

Comment: You've tagged this "plsql" but sp_spaceused looks like a SQL Server command. Is this on Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for Oracle:

Space allocated to tables and indexes:

```
select owner, segment_type, segment_name, sum(bytes)
from dba_segments
group by owner, segment_type, segment_name;
```

Free space:

```
select tablespace_name, sum(bytes) from dba_free_space group by tablespace_name;
```

Another more detailed query here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551402703363001567